# To get an image to be displayed in front of another one (to be continued)

Tags: html, css

I am stuck here! I have many images of an animal which are

In fact , small images of a face that are juxtaposed. all parts are visible except the eye !! And I want the eye to be seen. This is how I wrote the code. You can find the entire code in my [Github repo][3]. Here are the codes :

```
<div class ="leftDiv">
          <div class="container">
         
          <div class ="container image">
            <figure>
              <img src="alpaca/backgrounds/blue50.png" />
            </figure></div>
            
              <div class="container image"><figure>
              <img src="alpaca/eyes/default.png" />
            </figure></div>
              
              <div class="container  image"><figure>
                <img src="alpaca/ears/default.png" />
              </figure></div>
                <div class="container  image"><figure>
                  <img src="alpaca/nose.png" />
                </figure></div>
                  <div class="container image"><figure>
                <img src="alpaca/hair/default.png" />
              </figure></div>
              
                <div class="container  image"><figure>
                <img src="alpaca/leg/default.png" />
              </figure></div>
                
              
              <div class="container  image"><figure>
                <img src="alpaca/mouth/default.png" />
                </figure></div>
              <div class="container  image"><figure>
                <img src="alpaca/neck/default.png" />
                </figure></div>
                </div>
              </div>


 .leftDiv {
    position:absolute;
    left: 230px;
    top: 650px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px; 
  } 

  .container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:60px;
    left: -140px; 
  }
   
  .image { 
    position:absolute;
    z-index: unset;
    
  }

  .leftButton {
    color: black;
    text-align:right;
    font-size:35px;
    font-family: 'sofia';
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color:rgb(252, 228, 228);
    position:absolute;
    bottom: -410px;
    left:200px;
    
  }
```

Comment: please read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Also only ask oen question per question. If you have multiple questions, open multiple questions.

Comment: Dear @tacoshy  , did I make a mistake or write bad this post?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask | https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: add ``z-index: 10`` to the eye.

Comment: dear @AmirrezaAmini  , I finally found how to fix the issue. I had first to create a new class .eye and I added that new class to the <div> for the eye.  I have written this way : <div class=" container image eye>....</div> while before I wrote <div class=" container image >....</div>  . Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen where my error lies. I have several images that are juxtaposed and I want some to overlap others. This is where the z-index option is useful. z-index allows us to display items on top of others. Items that have a higher z-index are more visible than others. That's why I created a new class .eye {....; z-index: 10;}. This same class was added in my HTML file as follows:

....  instead of  ....  as noticed in the post. The problem is therefore resolved !! The eye is finally visible.